# How to make thunderbird automatically encrypt emails if possible?

Tags: email, encryption, thunderbird, pgp

When I start to compose a new email in Thunderbird, I want it to **automatically enable the `Encrypt` button** after I type a recipient's email address into the `To` field, **if I have that recipient's PGP key** in my keyring.

> Note: In [July 2020](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/78.0/releasenotes/), Thunderbird 78 was released with [built-in PGP support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/openpgp-thunderbird-howto-and-faq#w_does-thunderbird-support-openpgp). At this point it [regrettably](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1300459/how-does-mozilla-thunderbird-handles-my-key-and-can-it-import-directly-from-gpg) became impossible to continue to use Enigmail. Answers to this question that use enigmail are not valid to this question.

How can I make Thunderbird v78+ automatically enable PGP encryption of emails if the built-in Key Manager has a key for the recipient of the message?

Comment: There's literally a Thunderbird addon named [Encrypt if possible](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/encrypt-if-possible/) but it doesn't work with Thunderbird v78+

Comment: Seems like the latest Thunderbird updates closed a lot of options. Maybe these addons : [Arcus](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/arcus/?src=search) or [PGPGeek](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/pgpgeek/?src=search).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! This feature is available in Thunderbird Beta (114, which is due for release some time in July 2023), and I've played with it myself:

https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/e2ee/Te4059b3f9ccae287

> You are probably aware that as of today in the released Versions (and
> still by default in the above versions), when composing an email, in
> order to use e2ee, you must manually enable or disable encryption. While
> recent versions had already simplified the process of enabling or
> disabling, by showing reminders whether encryption is or isn't possible,
> the user still has to click buttons to make their decision.
>
> ...
>
> To enable this new automatism, open Thunderbird's settings, switch to
> the Privacy & Security tab, and scroll to section End-To-End Encryption,
> Automatic Use of Encryption.
>
> You may request that encryption is automatically enabled when possible.

If one navigates to `Edit > Settings > Privacy and Security` and then scrolls down to `Email End-to-End Encryption`, there is an "Automatic Use of Encryption" section:

[image]

Personally, I prefer to only have the first checkbox checked. However, one can play with the three options to decide which best suits their use case.